# selector not working in jquery after data loaded from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is the html

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">
        <!-- here to add button -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery code :-

```
$.ajax({
    url : "url.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : {someData : "some data"},
    success : function(data){
        $("#childDiv).html("<button id='clickMe'>Click me</button>");
    }
});
```

This code not working after element is added through ajax

```
$("#clickMe").on("click",function(){
    alert("please help!");
});
```

the #click me is not working.

How can I fix it, make it work ?

Comment: try `$(document).on("click","#clickMe",function() {})`

Comment: syntax error of double quotes, $("#childDiv").html("<button id='clickMe'>Click me</button>");

Answer (score -1):

Because you are creating `<button id='clickMe'>Click me</button>` **only after your asynchronous call returns**, the moment you are trying to attach an event handler to it, **it's not existent yet**. Also, you are trying to attach the button to an element that doesn't exist - you don't have a `div#ChildDiv`, but it has the CSS class `childDiv`.

Instead attach the event handler directly after creating it:

```
$.ajax({
  url : "url.php",
  type : "POST",
  data : {someData : "some data"},
  success : function(data) {
    // create your button in your ASYNCHRONOUSLY
    // executed success handler function
    $(".childDiv").first().html("<button id='clickMe'>Click me</button>");
    // now that it exists, attach the click handler
    $("#clickMe").on("click",function(){
      alert("please help!");
    });
  }
});
// code that appears here will be executed BEFORE the success function!
// (synchronously)
```

Comment: Hi @connexo, He is missing syntax error of #childDiv,

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda Good spot! Corrected and added that to the answer.